# CalDav on Outlook?

Tags: outlook, calendar, google-calendar-api, caldav

I'm looking for a good way to view CalDav calendars within Outlook.  I'm aware of the [OpenConnector](http://openconnector.org) project, but have not been happy with it thus far (re: stability issues & difficulty to configure).  Also, it appears to be supported by a single developer and there hasn't been a new release in about 18 months.

I know Google has a custom Outlook plugin to connect to their calendars (presumably via CalDav) and I'm aware of other Google-Outlook sync plugins - but are there other options for connecting Outlook clients to generic CalDav-compliant servers?

Answer (score 27):

I'm that single developer :)

The project desperately needs some new developer blood.  There are many people interested but no one ready to make that commitment necessary ( 10+ hours/week realistically ).   This is largely a reverse-engineering project.  I can easily spend 20-30 hours a week pouring other assembly in [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/).  I'm also a consultant so donating 10+ hrs/week to the community drastically affects my ability to meet my weekly quotas.

Reverse engineering such a large, old code-base is hard and the results are unpredictable.  But how Outlook interacts with MAPI plugins, especially when it comes to advanced features like Calendar sharing and delegation has not been ever documented by Microsoft.  I most likely, never will.  But a calendar plugin must meet those unspoken requirements and expose those undocumented APIs before it is taken seriously by Outlook.

If it weren't for that, Open Connector would have have been completed years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I use outlook for email only. And for Google calendar, used "eM Client" (http://www.emclient.com/) that supports caldav.

I tried Thunderbird but could not config caldav with the lightning Addon.